# S^1-bundles over non-aspherical manifolds

Tags: homotopy-theory

Is it true that an S^1-bundle over a non-aspherical manifold is still non-aspherical?

Comment: The homotopy long exact sequence of a fibration/fiber bundle gives you a very flexible and complete answer to this question, and others like it.

Answer (score 7):

The total space of a circle bundle over a non-aspherical manifold $B$ cannot be aspherical. If it were, then from the homotopy sequence of the bundle you would see that all homotopy groups of $B$ vanish above dimension $2$, and also $\pi_2(B)\cong\mathbb Z$. Thus the universal cover if $B$ is homotopy equivalent to $CP^\infty$, which has nonzero cohomology in all even dimensions, while the cohomology of any manifold vanish above the top dimension.